# Alias creation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, column-alias

How we can create alias of a column in table in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creation of aliases is very easy

```
SELECT tableColumnName as ColumnAlias FROM Table
```

Another thing is usage of the aliases, you must remember that the aliases are available after projection (select) this mean that you can't use those aliases in `FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING` sections. Is allowed only in `ORDER BY`.

EDIT: Usage of aliases

Tables:

```
STACK 
 - STACK_ID
 - STACK_NAME
 - STACK_ORDER
 - STACK_MIN
 - STACK_MAX
```

Wrong statement:

```
    SELECT 
     STACK_NAME, 
     STACK_MIN, 
     STACK_MAX, 
     STACK_MIN + STACK_MAX as STACK_SUM 
   FROM 
    STACK WHERE STACK_SUM = 10;
```

We use in WHERE section column that is not available on this level.

To solve this we have two options

Option One - We do the calculation in where statement

```
    SELECT 
     STACK_NAME, 
     STACK_MIN, 
     STACK_MAX, 
     STACK_MIN + STACK_MAX as STACK_SUM 
   FROM 
    STACK WHERE STACK_MIN + STACK_MAX = 10;
```

Option Two - We create a temporary table

```
WITH STACK_SUM_TAB AS (
 SELECT 
  STACK_NAME, 
  STACK_MIN, 
  STACK_MAX, 
  STACK_MIN + STACK_MAX as STACK_SUM 
 FROM STACK 
)

 SELECT 
  STACK_NAME, 
  STACK_MIN, 
  STACK_MAX, 
  STACK_SUM 
 FROM STACK_SUM_TAB WHERE STACK_SUM = 10;
```

Comment: Here you go. And that mr. is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select somecolumn as foo from bar where foo = 5
```

Comment: thnks sir can u explain why we use this alias concept plz

Comment: Alias are useful when you have complex queries with long column names coming from different tables. Giving them more meaningful names improves the readability of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnname AS [ColumnAliasName] FROM [TableName]
```

Comment: SELECT t.columnname AS [ColumnAliasName] FROM [TableName] t WHERE t.columnname = [Your Condition value here]